# C# or VB: Get the variable type from a property

Tags: vb.net, reflection, types

I'm trying get a member based on a String from a class and then get the type but I'm not having any luck.

```
Public Class Monster
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property EatsPeople As Boolean
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

To get the details for the member "EatsPeople" I do:

```
Dim t = GetType(Monster) ' Get the type of the Product entity.
Dim fieldMemberInfo = t.GetMember("EatsPeople", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance).Single()
```

No matter what combo I try, I either get Nothing or a RuntimePropertyType

```
Dim x = fieldMemberInfo.GetType
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to get the type of the "EatsPeople" property.  For that, it is easier to use `PropertyInfo`.

e.g.

```
Dim t = GetType(Monster) ' Get the type of the Product entity.
Dim propertyInfo = t.GetProperty("EatsPeople") 'Get the property info

Dim x = propertyInfo.PropertyType 'Get the type of the "Eats People" property.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the property Name like this:

```
Dim t1 As PropertyInfo = fieldMemberInfo
Dim t2 = t1.PropertyType.FullName
```